# How do I port MultiCheckComboBox to PySide?

Tags: python, pyside

I want the items in a combobox to be checkable. I have found a way to do this [here](https://github.com/spanners/pyqt4-examples/blob/master/MultiSelectionExample/).

This specific example uses PyQt and since I use PySide, it needs some modifications to work.

The first error I get is about `QStringList` which I replaced with `[]`.

Then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MultiCheckComboBox.py", line 401, in data
    if not value.isValid():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isValid'
```

I am not sure what needs to be changed to fix the above error.

Comment: Summerfield, who literally wrote the book on PyQt, has notes on porting things to PySide here: http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html. Also, some additional notes can be found here on porting Summerfield's book from PyQt to PySide, which could have some stuff that is useful in general: https://github.com/EricThomson/PySideSummer.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt4 (by default) returns some values as instances of `QVariant` (although it can be configured to return a native Python type). PySide however, always converts to native Python types.

Your code is assuming that PyQt4 will be using `QVariant`. That line of code assumes `value` is a `QVariant`. You will need to change it to:

```
if value is not None:
```

in this case, however this is unlikely to be the only instance of a `QVariant` in this code and the modification you need to make to those will be dependent on the `QVariant` function that the code is trying to call.